How to import the detailed map of rural roads I need for a project from Google Maps using QGIS
I need a detailed map of rural roads for a project. Google Maps seems to have that information, but I don't understand how to import it to QGIS.
I need accurate and detailed information on roads and highways, for a place in rural India. I have tried to trace them off the Google satellite plug-in on QGIS, but the my polyline file has many errors. I can see that Google Maps has the route data I need - but I can't figure out how to import it to QGIS.
I know that I can import individual points, on hand-drawn lines/polygons as a KML, but is there anyway to get access to Google's existing road data?

If you want highly accurate data, you probably don't want Google's linework. In the rural US, I found Maps imagery off by 10-16 feet. Besides, scraping data is a TOS violation.

I'm not sure if the data is available at all (in a useful format), but if it is, you might want to read Google's terms of service first. You may have to pay a fee. The obvious starting point for free data would be OpenStreetMap. Have you looked at that yet?

https://socalgis.org/2019/11/06/add-google-maps-to-qgis-3/
